# Good references to start researching on dark energy knowing only graduate general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, resource-recommendations, cosmic-microwave-background, dark-energy

I'd like to research on Dark Energy, but I only know (Schutz-Foster-Carroll) general relativity. Can anyone indicate to me some good books to start to research this topic?

I'm interested in how to test a dark energy candidate on the experimental data.

Comment: Nobody understands anything about dark energy beyond the fact that it's an extra term in Einstein's GR equation.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t mean a dark *matter* candidate?

Comment: Thanks @PeterShor and G.Smith. I want to research on dark energy. I read a review on dark energy (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11467-013-0300-5), but I don't know the minimum to understand very well. So I'm asking for some introductory books on dark energy.

Comment: @Caetes: since nobody really has any good guess as to where dark energy comes from, it's very hard to say what background you need to explain it. Pretty much anything in high-energy physics or quantum gravity could be relevant.